# halo effect in java2d

Tags: widget, transparency, java-2d

I am drawing a small indicator widget over another visual representation of a system.

This widget is essentially an altitude indicator: a vertical bar and a triangle that points at the current camera altitude. In crude ascii art:

```
|
|<
|
|
|
```

More often than not, visibility is hampered by the layer below. Is there an easy way to create an aesthetically pleasing white "halo" around my widget in java2D?

Cheers

Comment: Would adapting some of this code: http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/reflections/index.html help? It's got gradients and transparency, which is what I think a halo would use when I picture it

Comment: No, looking at this code, it does not seem to be what I want. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I draw lines with a thickness of three pixels in
white, then again with a thickness of one pixel in red.
Experiment with the widths, line cap style and anti-aliasing rendering hints
to get something that looks good to you.

Achieving halos for text is more difficult: you have to call
`Font.createGlyphVector` to get the outline of the characters,
draw the outlines as lines in white and then draw the string over the
top in red using `Graphics2D.drawString`.